# How to calculate this binary operation?

Tags: aes

I  found this binary operation, however It is the first time that I found this  operator '.'   :

That is the equation:

02 • 63 = 00000010 • 01100011 = 11000110

I don't understand how 0 • 0=1

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: This operator $\cdot$, like multiplication?
Check the wiki for how binaray multiplication works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier
Though binary multiplication by 2 is simply a left shift.

Comment: " 00000010 • 01100011 = 11000110 " stands for a variety of operators •  . Examples include ordinary multiplication when values are in binary; ordinary multiplication modulo $2^8$; carry-less multiplication; and multiplication in $GF(2^8)$ for any polynomial. We have no way to guess which without context. Regarding " 0 • 0 = 1 ", that seems to be an error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with cryptography at all. It is just regular multiplication, where numbers are written in binary.

Comment: @tylo, I found this operation in the description of an example of AES.http://www.iu.edu.jo/files/FacultyIT/Computer-Science/Courses/IT%20Security/stalling%20Computer%20security%20PP%20slides/Documents/Documents/AES-Example.pdf   page 7

Comment: I'd guess it's multiplication in the binary finite field GF(2^8).

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thank you very much, I found a clear exemple, http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch04s04.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This '.' is not 'AND' operation , its **modular multiplication in the Galois Field $$GF(2^8)$$** and **other operation**  $$\oplus$$ used in Mix Column Step of AES encrytion is  **modular addition in the Galois Field $$GF(2^8)$$**. Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1usFRN4LCMcfIV7UjHNuQg) to youtube channel by Christoff Paar where you can understand well, Watch lecture 7 and 8.

Hope it helps.